# How do I put HQL in an entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entity, hql

I have a Hibernate entity that I would like to put a method in. This method would call the entity manager and run a prepared statement, but I don't know how to instantiate the entity manager. Whenever I try, to autowire it like so:

```
@Autowired
private transient EntityManager entityManager;
```

the entityManager is null when I run the application. Autowiring works for all my other classes. Why can't I autowire the entityManager in my entity, and how do I execute my query in the Entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Autowired is for beans, classes with @Service or @Component. Classes marked @Configuration can also use @Autowired. New instances of these classes are made and managed by Spring, if you try to create new instances of those classes @Autowired won't work there either. Such as `MyClass myClass = new MyClass()`

Classes marked with @Entity are not managed beans, they are made by the entity manager when you query them from the database, but when you create a new row you make a new instance. Spring doesn't do it's magic to them. You should call your stored procedure from a @Service just like you would use a @Repository or entity manager to save an @Entity.

Comment: My DAO is annotated with @Component, does that matter?

Comment: No, an ```@Entity``` cannot have ```@Autowired```, why can't you put your stored procedure call in a ```@Service```?